# Two weeks in hell documentary song during selection results

Tags: soundtrack

What is the song played in the first 1:45 minutes of [this video](http://wn.com/two_weeks_in_hell_part_9_of_9) from *Two Weeks In Hell*?

Comment: The talking is so much louder than the soft plucking of the music, that's likely why there's no luck on the automatic services. It might be library music intended to be used for movies/TV, otherwise someone here should be able to ID it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly just a guitar loop recorded for incidental background music, but it's a very close match to the Johnny Cash version of NIN's "[Hurt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vt1Pwfnh5pc)" (a video well worth watching!).  The producers probably wanted a similar sound to that song, but didn't want to pay the licensing fee for the original.